# Find $\sup_{f\in F}|f(\frac{1}{2})|$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Hey I need some help with this analysis problem.

> Let F be the set of twice differentiable functions $f(x)$ on [0,1] such that $f'(0)=f(1)=0,$ and $\int_0^1 |f''(x)|^2dx=1. $ Find $\sup_{f\in F}|f(\frac{1}{2})|$.

I used the FTC and Holder's inequality to find the bound which is 1/2, but I have trouble to find this specific function such that satisfies these conditions.. Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Do you mean $f(0)=f(1)=0$, not $f'(0)=f(1)=0$?

Comment: Also, I suspect no such $f$ exists; you should instead approximate such a function.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{6}}$.

Indeed, consider a function $f\in F$. Clearly we have
$$\eqalign{f(x)&= \int_x^1f'(t)(-1)dt=\Big[(1-t)f'(t)\big]_x^1-\int_x^1(1-t)f''(t)dt\cr
&=-(1-x)f'(x)-\int_x^1(1-t)f''(t)dt\cr
&=-(1-x)\int_0^xf''(t)dt-\int_x^1(1-t)f''(t)dt\cr
&=(x-1)\int_0^xf''(t)dt+\int_x^1(t-1)f''(t)dt\cr
&=\int_0^1(\max(t,x)-1)f''(t)dt\cr
}$$
By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have
$$
|f(x)|^2\leq\int_0^1|f''(t)|^2dt\cdot \int_0^1|(\max(t,x)-1)|^2dt=\int_0^1|(\max(t,x)-1)|^2dt
$$
The last integral is easy to calculate and we have
$$
\int_0^1|(\max(t,x)-1)|^2dt=(x-1)^2\int_0^x dt+\int_x^1(t-1)^2dt
=\frac{2x+1}{3}(x-1)^2
$$
Thus we have shown that
$$
|f(x)|\leq (1-x)\sqrt{\frac{2x+1}{3}}
$$
With equality if $f''$ is proportional to $u\mapsto  1-\max(u,x) $,  by the equality case in Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. So,
$$
\sup_{f\in F}|f(x)|= (1-x)\sqrt{\frac{2x+1}{3}}
$$
In particular, if $x=1/2$ we have $
\sup_{f\in F}|f(\frac{1}{2})|=\sqrt{\frac{1}{6}}
$.